# Navy acronyms in "Flight of the Intruder"

Tags: flight-of-the-intruder

I'm watching Danny Glover's [Flight of the Intruder](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099587) (1991) on Netflix. I'm able to figure out *most* of the slang and acronyms, but I can't figure out these 2:

1. **B.N.** — Example: "I heard you were my new B.N., sir"
2. **B.'s** — Example: "I'm not even rated on the B's!"

In the case of #1, it's apparently some sort of officer or job — navigator? In the case of #2, it's a type of airplane, and I can only judge that I do not believe it means B-52.

Comment: Would you be able to provide either clips from the movie showing the use of these acronyms, or provide the dialog itself?

Comment: @MattD I don't have any clips other than the trailer, but I added some dialogue.

Comment: Why did you rollback my edit? We have a strict policy against genre tags in any use other than for ID questions and even those are questionable.

Comment: @Catija I was combining the tags but then I thought better of it and reverted to just the one you suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "B" is almost certainly the A-6**B** variant (for [Iron Hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Iron_Hand)) of the [Grumman A-6 Intruder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_A-6_Intruder).

> Four hundred and eighty-four units of the A-6A variant were built; nineteen were later converted to the A-6B version during the Vietnam War that specialized in attacking enemy air defense units.

<sub>**Source:** Michael Green, [United States Naval Aviation 1911-2014](https://www.pen-and-sword.co.uk/United-States-Naval-Aviation-1911-2014-Paperback/p/10881), Pen & Sword Aviation, 2015.</sub>

---

I believe the following is the relevant part of the movie:

---

**Addendum:** "B/N" stands for "Bombardier / Navigator", as [mentioned](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/50040/36669) by Catija.

Comment: Spot on. If you hadn't put that i would've!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the Wiki page of [Naval Acronyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._Navy_acronyms#B):

> B/N - Bombardier/Navigator (no longer used)

It doesn't list anything for "b" or "b's".

Comment: I was looking at the same list. I'm wondering if it could possibly be the BZ one at the bottom, but pronounced phonetically?

Comment: Maybe... I'd think "BZ" would be pronounced "bee zee", though... Hmmm.

Comment: Yeah, I've asked OP to provide either clips or dialog to try and figure out how they're said and what was going on to try and determine what they might mean. That's the problem with acronyms: without context, no one will likely know what they're for.

Comment: @MattD I provided the requested example, but to explain - I assumed the people responding would've seen the film. I don't think it's B.Z.; it could be, but now I'm thinking that maybe it just means bombardier and they were being referred to in the plural.

Comment: @Hack-R I've never even **heard** of it, let alone seen it.

Comment: @Catija how about Iron Eagle?