# In Vietnam, did U.S. combat aviators ever wear camouflage flight suits?

Tags: historical-accuracy, flight-of-the-intruder

In [Flight of the Intruder](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099587) (1991), LCDR [Virgil Cole](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099587/characters/nm0000353) (Willem Dafoe) wears a [tigerstripe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tigerstripe)† [flight suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_suit). Though I have seen lots of photographs of U.S. aviators during the Vietnam War, I had never seen a camouflage [flight suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_suit).  In Vietnam, did U.S. combat aviators ever wear camouflage [flight suits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_suit)?

---

[image]

<sub>[Source](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099587/mediaviewer/rm3267952129)</sub>

---

---

† <sub>Richard Denis Johnson, [Tiger Patterns — A guide to the Vietnam War's tigerstripe combat fatigue patterns and uniforms](https://schifferbooks.com/products/tiger-patterns-fatigue), Schiffer Military Aviation History, 1999.</sub>

---

**Related:** [Navy acronyms in "Flight of the Intruder"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/50036/36669)

Comment: I wonder if this is really a question related to movies. Reading only the title, I could be searching the [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/) stack. And the body doesn't help much to link to movies.

Comment: From [official air force](https://www.afmc.af.mil/About-Us/History/Uniforms/igphoto/2002737708/): (typo included) "*1960s - 1**0**70s - Vietnam era flight suit. Standard flight suits were K-2s, and these eventually gave way to the Nomex flight suit of today.*" FWIW: a quick search shows **0** K2's with any kind of camouflage. All plain orange/grey/solid. As Vietnam war officially ended in 1975, *maybe* some other flight suits were made, found none of them though.

Comment: I'm not sure which of the following would take precedence, as I wasn't in Vietnam: camo flight suit to not be seen by enemy, or orange to be seen by rescue helicopter. If the rescuers can't see you, you don't get picked up.

Comment: @CGCampbell If one only flies over water, an orange flight suit should be fine. The [CSAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combat_search_and_rescue) rescuers could see a downed pilot wearing camo in the jungle if he did pop a smoke grenade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short yes (But, not officially)

[image]

(unable to find source for image)

[image]

> Photograph of Roy T. Church in a camouflage flight suit, smoking a cigar at Da Nang Air Base, Vietnam, circa 1968-1969.

https://digitalcollections.museumofflight.org/items/show/25176

Gathered from forum posts:

never officially issued, ones that found themselves in aircrew hands were through private sale, privately produced and procured.

Though Tigerstripe was an official camo issued to the Vietnamese military of the period, it was not US government issue. As found below, the camo pattern found itself into the hands of the US military there through other means of production and sale.

From a forum that asks same questions

[image]

> from Bob C among the thousands of posts in that thread and he notes:

"If you look in the lengthy Tiger Stripe pinned thread, you will see a couple of shots of the Recreational Garments tagged tiger stripe flight suits. These have been referred to as CIA issue. What they really are is, someone heard there was going to be a order coming around for a isue of these tiger stripe suits. One very smart person living on Okinawa, got wind of this order, went to the tailor shop in Tokyo at the Daimaru dept store in the Ginza district, and bought as many sets as he could. As soon as he got them, he had tags made, had them sewn in, and then resold them to the agencies that requested them. Does this make them Ciso or CIA? Not in my mind, it just shows great GI smarts."

https://www.usmilitariaforum.com/forums/index.php?/topic/319219-usmc-flyers-tiger-stripe-flight-suit-cloth-label-recreation-associates/

Same forum, sale thread:

> USAF Fighter types stationed in Thailand (or at least at Udorn) stopped wearing them when the Nomex became available. My Tiger Stripe Flight Suit was made downtown and never worn.

https://www.usmilitariaforum.com/forums/index.php?/topic/195099-tiger-stripes-flight-suit-thoughts/

Seems more common with helo flight crew, by the time the  more common flightsuits were issued these custom flights suits disappeared.

[image]

https://www.usmilitariaforum.com/forums/index.php?/topic/217912-vietnam-era-camo-flight-suit-made-in-thailand/

Further info:

[image]

> Flight Suits: ... They came in a wide choice of solid colors and camouflage patterns. The solid colors were khaki, olive drab, and orange. The camouflage patterns were tree pattern (tiger stripes) and leopard spots.

> The flight suit that were of the "tree pattern" camouflage was issued to the squadron while we were still in Okinawa and prior to our first deployment to Vietnam. The first time I saw this camouflage pattern was when it was worn by Vietnamese Marines who were attending NCO courses at Marine Corps Recruit Depot (MCRD) San Diego, California, in 1961. I was then undergoing recruit training and the Vietnamese Marines (thuy quan luc-chien) were billeted in quonset huts next to my platoon. I had a feeling then that I would be seeing more of that uniform again, and, indeed, less than three years later, I was wearing a uniform in that camouflage pattern in combat. Later, that camo pattern was also worn by Army and Navy personnel and became popularly known by the more fierce sounding name - "tiger stripes camouflage".

https://www.angelfire.com/de/HMM365Vietnam/2equipclothing.html

[image]

> The first tiger stripe camo uniforms were created in the 1950s for the Vietnamese military. Derived from French leopard and lizard camo patterns dating to World War II, the Vietnamese version was better able to distort a soldier’s body shape. Combined with some British uniform components, the tiger stripe camo pattern was the preferred uniform pattern of choice in the bush.
>
> During the Vietnam War, in the early 1960s, tiger stripe camo was embraced by U.S. military advisors, mostly Special Forces working with South Vietnamese military members. Special operators liked the way the pattern blended into the jungles better than the standard issue olive drab fatigues being issued to regular Army soldiers.
>
> **U.S. Army, Navy, Air Force and Marines all wore some type of tiger stripe camo uniform during Vietnam** depending on their units and on their military occupational specialty. **Many of the uniforms were made and purchased in country or made in the region**.

https://www.usamm.com/blogs/news/tiger-stripe-camo-does-it-hold-any-significance

[image]

Comment: These were *non-official* suits, right? Govt didn't pay for it?

Comment: @OldPadawan absolutely, private purchase only. Non GI !

Comment: Thank you.  Before you posted your answer, I was doing my own research and found [this post](http://mightyoriskany.blogspot.com/2008/03/oriskanys-most-colorful-co.html) about Richard Bellinger, which contains a photo of what appears to be him wearing a camouflage flight suit.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo - hi thats a cool read! His camo is not Tigerstripe though, he has a rare Beo Gam (leopard in Vietnamese) pattern flightsuit, also found early in the Vietnam War period (But similar to Tigerstripe, found themselves sourced from outlets like Takashimaya).

Comment: @blobbymcblobby To me, it looked like the camouflage used by the USMC in the last stage of WWII in the Pacific

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo - absolutely, it looks like ERDL - until you put it side by side with the other. Before the nomex issued suits, leopard spot was also pretty popular at the time, along with Tiger. In terms of looks, ERDL style was closer in blob pattern to US Woodland, whereas Beo Gam was more spotty like a ..leopard..